# Getting Error: BrokenCount >0 now, but was not an issue before

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

I have virtual machine running Ubuntu version 18.04.3 Bionic Beaver. Back in Dec 2021 I did a patch upgrade and downloads all the debians upgrade locally for future uses. I installed those packages using  `dpkg -i ./folder/*` to get my Ubuntu to 18.04.6. Now I messed up my OS and decided to reimage it back to my original 18.04.3. Installing those debian packages using the same method above now giving me `Error: BrokenCount >0` using update-notifier/apt-check now.

I got curious so I did the `sudo apt-get -f install --download-only` to get all the missing dependencies. Here are some of the examples

```
dirmngr_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
gnupg_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
gnupg-l10n_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.6_all.deb
gnupg-utils_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
gpg_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
gpg-agent_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
gpgconf_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
```

Upgrading those seems to give me 0:0 for apt-check now. While it is nice, but some of the patches will be deployed. Thus, I might need a reliable ways to ensure that I can get the machine back to certain version. It was the reason why I download all those deb packages. Some of the files in the list above has recently been added to the ubuntu in 2022. Why is it affecting my current dependencies? I thought I had download the packages back in 2021. Should it not depend on say gnupg-utils_2.2.4-1ubuntu**1.4**_amd64.deb which is what I currently had saved off back in 2021, instead of gnupg-utils_2.2.4-1ubuntu**1.6**_amd64.deb (2022 files)

What can I do to prevent this from happening in the future? Is it not OK to save off the debian packages for future use?

Comment: Why do you download pakets manually and install them with `dpkg` instead of using `apt`?

Comment: @Panki the reason why I download them manually was because I have a device that I deployed and does not have an access to the internet. maybe im doing it wrong? genuine question